# (Linux) Allow JavaFX AlwaysOnTop Window to bypass the x11 window manager

Tags: java, linux, javafx-8, overlay, x11

I recently asked a similar question about this for OSX and found a solution using the com.sun.glass package. However, this solution does not seem to work on X11-based desktop environments.

The issue:
I am trying to write a borderless window overlay that can be placed above ALL other desktop components, including the dock and menubar of any given Linux desktop environment which uses x11. Currently, when I use AlwaysOnTop(true) with my JavaFX window, the window is placed above all other windows but is NOT placed above the window managers UI (taskbar) due to it having a higher window level. The screenshot below shows what happens when using AlwaysOnTop: the entirety of the vertical white window should be placed **above the taskbar** but is instead forced below it. See screenshot:[image]

There is a solution for this issue with Qt through using the x11bypasswindowmanager window flag, so I figured it must be possible through Java!

The only current solution I have is to use [wmctrl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl) directly through the commandline using a subprocess. This is not really suitable, as a lot of linux systems to not come with wmctrl installed.

Below is the code snippet I am using to generate the window in the above screenshot:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 3000));
        primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        primaryStage.setX(800);
        primaryStage.setY(0);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tell me the name of your product so that I can never use it :) In X Window System applications don't enforce behaviour, they make polite requests and WM implements them as it sees fit. I **configure** my panel so that application windows cannot cover it (unless in full screen mode) because I **want** this behaviour. Mark your window always-on-top like every other well behaved X11 application. Don't abuse override-redirect windows to go around policies you don't like.

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, I do not see how what you have suggested is at all a useful solution for my **screenshot overlay application**. I have already said in the above post that I wish to avoid using wmctrl, and I am looking for a java-based solution for the problem at hand. You, as an individual, may not want this behaviour, however, in my ideal implementation of this, you (the end user) will have the option to enable or disable this automatic, or as you may word 'forced', above-all window. Personally, I don't want to have to configure an **overlay** when it should already work.

Comment: I already have an option to enable or disable overlapping *in the panel* where it belongs.

Comment: Having said that, no, JavaFX doesn't appear to expose any methods of doing what you want (and yes, it does expose fewer things than Qt or gtk do).